# Create a batch file to control services from multiple servers

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create a .bat file that will give me option to chose between different servers and perform actions such as stop/start services. So far I am getting System error 67 has occurred.The network name cannot be found. Is there a better way to do this. or can I chose the server name from a pop up option.

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO 1.server1
ECHO 2.server2
ECHO 3.server3
ECHO 4.server4
ECHO.

set /p server_name=Enter server name:

IF %server_name%== 1 GOTO app1
IF %server_name%== 2 GOTO app2
IF %server_name%== 3 GOTO app3
IF %server_name%== 4 GOTO app4

:app1
call:restart "server1"
GOTO End
:app2
 call:restart "server2"
 GOTO End

:app3
 call:restart "server3"
 GOTO End

:app4
call:restart "server4"
GOTO End

:restart
net use \\%~1/User:%username%
SC \\%~1 Stop service
timeout 10
SC \\%~1 Start service
GOTO End
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of debugging your file, I'd like to present you a different solution:

On the servers where you want to restart your services create this bat file:

```
@ECHO OFF
:STOP
SC STOP <your_service>
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
SC QUERY <your_service> | find /I "STATE" | find "STOPPED"
if errorlevel 1 goto :STOP    
SC START <your_service>
```

Now, create on your servers tasks with the task scheduler. Don't set any triggers but make the task execute your newly created bat file. Select any options you need (like a specific user with a specific password, whether to run the script when no one is logged in or not, whether to run it with admin priveledges or not, etc.) and give it name (your_task).

Finally, modify your script like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
ECHO 1.server1
ECHO 2.server2
ECHO 3.server3
ECHO 4.server4
ECHO.

:SELECT
set /p server_name=Enter server name:

IF %server_name%==1 GOTO app1
IF %server_name%==2 GOTO app2
IF %server_name%==3 GOTO app3
IF %server_name%==4 GOTO app4
GOTO SELECT
:app1
SCHTASKS /RUN /S "server1" /TN "your_task"
GOTO End
:app2
SCHTASKS /RUN /S "server2" /TN "your_task"
GOTO End
:app3
SCHTASKS /RUN /S "server3" /TN "your_task"
GOTO End
:app4
SCHTASKS /RUN /S "server4" /TN "your_task"
GOTO End
:End
```

You can also pass a user and a password to the `SCHTASKS` command if needed.

It should be clear how it works. I'd recommend taking a closer look at the first bat file. Using this:

```
SC \\%~1 Stop service
timeout 10
SC \\%~1 Start service
```

might cause trouble. Sometimes service won't stop within 10 seconds out of various reasons. Trying to start the service while it hasn't stopped yet, will result in an error and the service will remain stopped.

Instead, our bat script within the scheduled task will try to stop the service, then wait for 5 seconds (yes, -n 6 means 5 seconds ^^) and then it will check whether the service has the state "STOPPED". If it is, it will start it, otherwise, it will re-try to stop it, wait 5 more seconds and so on.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your well described explanation. It was very helpful and works as expected. I have one more question. I am just curious,In my code why the function is not passing the right argument. I am expecting to pass the "server name"in restart function wherever it says \%~1. Is there anything I am missing.

Comment: @user2410266 Possible error: in the line `net use \\%~1/User:%username%` there should be a space between **1** and **/**. It might also work when you just skip the `net use` command. `SC \\%~1 Stop service - timeout 10 - SC \\%~1 Start service` might already do the job.